# Gauge Higgs Unification

Tags: gauge-theory, higgs

http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.6023 Gauge Higgs unification .

Does gauge higgs unification has been proved ？
If so , what is it exactly meaning ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is cold dark matter made of Higgs bosons?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109991/)

Comment: The question I've linked cites the same paper you do. The paper makes assumptions about the Higgs boson that have been experimentally disproved.

Comment: Yes it was duplicate .

Comment: if the gauge higgs unification is disproved , would it be the gauge-dark matter unification ?

Comment: Don't know, sorry. It's not my area, I just happened to remember the duplicate question.